# Adding services to a Controller through "container.service_subscriber" not working as expected

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am trying to use the `container.service_subscriber` tag on my Controller to make some services available without injecting them through the constructor. In our project we don't want to use the `autowiring` and also can't use the autoconfigure option.

The structure of the Controller is as follow:

I have a base `BaseController` which extends from the `AbstractFOSRestController` of FOSRestBundle which has some common used methods for all my Controllers. That service will be used as `parent` for my other Controllers.

The service definition looks like this:

```
WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController:
    class: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController
    abstract: true
    arguments:
        - "@service1"
        - "@service2"
        - ...

WM\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController:
    parent: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController
    public: true
    #autowire: true
    class: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController
    tags:
        - { name: 'container.service_subscriber'}
        - { name: 'container.service_subscriber', key: 'servicexyz', id: 'servicexyz' }
```

The class looks like this:

```
/**
 * User controller.
 */
class UserController extends AbstractCRUDController implements ClassResourceInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getSubscribedServices(), [
        'servicexyz' => ServiceXYZ::class,
        ]);
    }
   .......
}
```

The problem I have is, if I set `autowire: false`, it always automatically sets the full container and with this the appropriate deprecation message (as I am not setting it myself):

> User Deprecated: Auto-injection of the container for "WM\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController" is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. Configure it as a service instead.

When setting `autowire: true` Symfony does respect the `container.service_subscriber` tag and only sets the partial container (ServiceLocator), which also would solve the deprecation message. I would have expected that autowiring should not make any differences in this case because I am explicitly telling the service which other services it should have.
Am I using the tags wrong or do I have a general problem in understanding how to subscribe a service to a Controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic issue is that the builtin service subscriber functionality will only inject the service locator into the constructor.  A conventional controller which extends AbstractController uses autoconfigure to basically override this and uses setContainer instead of the constructor.

```
# ApiBundle/Resources/config/services.yaml
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: false
    autoconfigure: false

  Api\Controller\UserController:
    public: true
    tags: ['container.service_subscriber']
```

```
class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedServices()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::getSubscribedServices(), [
            // ...
            'logger' => LoggerInterface::class,
        ]);
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $url = $this->generateUrl('user'); // Works as expected

        // $signer = $this->get('uri_signer'); // Fails as expected

        $logger = $this->get('logger'); // Works as expected

        return new Response('API Index Controller ' . get_class($this->container));
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
    API Index Controller Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator
```

Indicating that a service locator (as opposed to the global container is being injected).

You can also configure your service to use the setContainer method and eliminate the need for a constructor.  Either approach will work.

```
  Api\Controller\UserController:
    public: true
    tags: ['container.service_subscriber']
    calls: [['setContainer', ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and response. But isn't this actually contrary to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#aliased-services)? And [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html#defining-a-service-subscriber) it is actually even saying if I don't want to use autoconfigure I should just use the tag. Also tested with only autoconfigure enabled which didn't change the behaviour, only way to have it as expected (or at least as I understand) was with autowire enabled.

Comment: Found a solution to my problem. There was actually already [an issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33755) on the symfony project. What I had missing was the call to `['setContainer', ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]` which would give me the `ServiceLocator`. I tried it once with the `service_container` but that would always contain the full container, so that probably confused me there.

Comment: Cool.  I was trying to figure out how to use calls but never tried using the Psr ContainerInterface.  I added it as an option to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem is to extend the service definition of the Controller with a call to `setContainer` to inject the `'@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface'` service:

```
WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController:
    class: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController
    abstract: true
    arguments:
        - "@service1"
        - "@service2"
        - ...
    calls: 
        - ['setContainer', ['@Psr\Container\ContainerInterface']]

WM\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController:
    parent: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\BaseController
    public: true
    class: WM\ApiBundle\Controller\UserController
    tags:
        - { name: 'container.service_subscriber'}
        - { name: 'container.service_subscriber', key: 'servicexyz', id: 'servicexyz' }
```

This will give me a `ServiceLocator` as container containing only the regiestered services instead of the full container without using the `autowire` option.
Sidenote: Setting the `@service_container` would inject the full container.

For completeness, there was already an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/33755) on the symfony project where this was discussed.